# drop down list changed

Tags: javascript

in my application I need to check if a drop down list has changed or not. can you please let me know how I should write it?

```
if (document.form.dropdownlist.???)
```

I don't know what to write instead of ????

Comment: What part of the drop down list? The selected item? The items in the list? It's style?

Comment: There is no "flag" for change, there is an event fired when the selected option changes. [Read this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) as an intro to how events work

Comment: @ Karl Nicoll . I am looking for the time when the value of a drop down list is changed.

Answer (score 3):

You could give this dropdownlist an unique id:

```
<select name="foo" id="foo">
    ...
</select>
```

and then subscribe for the `onchange` event (make sure you make the subscription once the DOM is loaded, for example in the body onload method):

```
var ddl = document.getElementById('foo');
ddl.onchange = function() {
    alert('the value has changed');
};
```

Comment: i believe he is referring to weather the contents of the select has changed and not the selected item of the select.

Comment: @Achshar, of course that's possible. Many things are possible when a question is not clear.

Comment: so how can this be done? maybe store the innerhtml of select on page load and compare it to current innerhtml when the function is called..

Comment: I am looking for the time when the value of a drop down list is changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count=3;

 function check()
 {
    var obj =new Array();
    obj=document.getElementById("list");
    checkLength(obj.length);
 }
 function checkLength(len)
 {
    if(len>count)
    {
       alert("Drop down size changed");
    }
 }
```

- Take three option elements in select element.
- Call the method check() using  onchange()  to get the size of drop down list.
- The variable count is    used to store the drop down list size    .
- So that it can be used to check if drop down list is changed.